# How to get string between two strings from Axios request?

Tags: node.js, regex, axios

I have an axios request that gets a webpage and I need pull a string from the response data between 2 reference strings.

Example: I want to get `Stuff` from the response data string.

> "theID":1234,"theMap":"Stuff"}]};

```
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        const firstvariable = `theMap":"`;
        const secondvariable = `"}]}`;
        const data = response.data;
        const source = data.match(
          new RegExp(firstvariable + "(.*)" + secondvariable)
        );
        console.log(source); // should be Stuff
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
```

Regardless of what regex I try from searching on stackoverflow / googling, nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Axios takes care of deserializing the JSON into a plain ol' object. So, all you need is something like this:

```
const response = await axios.get(url);

// since didn't actually give us an example of your JSON,
// you'll need to figure out the correct path.
const stuff = response.data?.path?.to?.stuff;
```

Comment: I should have clarified sorry, the response is not a json object. it's a webpage source like a giant string. inside it there is a script tag with a json object in there as I showed above. I'm hoping to just find between the 2 strings with regex instead.